# new SSD - APFS not in list of options for format

Tags: ssd, apfs, disk-format

I just put a new SSD in my 2011 Macbook Pro. I booted into Internet Recovery (CMD+R), ran Disk Utility and followed the instructions to go to 'erase' and format as APFS. Unfortunately, the 'Format' dropdown menu only shows the standard Mac OS Extended options, MS-DOS and ExtFat.

[image]

Do I need to boot into Mac OS from a flash drive and then format the SSD from there... or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Booted into Disk Utility" ?? Do you mean Internet Recovery? Or another macOS installer on USB? Or what exactly? Also what version of macOS are you running there? If it isn't Mojave or High Sierra you won't get APFS

Comment: my bad - booted into Internet Recovery and ran Disk Utility form there. I was previously running High Sierra on the old drive, but there's no OS currently installed as this drive is brand new and the only one accessible.

Comment: Format it as HFS+ and if you are installing Mojave it will likely be converted during installation.

Comment: That's Mac OS Extended, Journaled, correct? It's on a 2011 MBP so High Sierra is as far as I can go - will it still be converted... able to be converted afterwords?

Comment: What OS are you running in Internet Recovery?

Comment: I think in HS APFS is optional, sorry, it's been a while. But yes to your disk format Q.

Comment: I had to install Lion --> EL Capitan --> High Sierra. It converted to APFS with 10.13 (High Sierra)

Comment: Disk Utility looks like it's pre-Yosemite [skeuomorphic dots top left] which will have no idea what APFS is. Try booting to Internet Recovery using Cmd/Opt/R & you should get the chance to install the latest OS the machine can run, rather than the one it came with. You should also get a Disk Utility that understands APFS.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I believe that's exactly it. I didn't discover the CMD/**OPT**/R until I was up and running the lonnnnnnnng way (see previous comment). If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped - dropping in a quick answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk Utility looks like it's pre-Yosemite [skeuomorphic dots top left] which will have no idea what APFS is.
Try booting to Internet Recovery using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>     <kbd>R</kbd>   & you should get the chance to install the latest OS the machine can run, rather than the one it came with.

You should also get a Disk Utility that understands APFS.